# .replace replaces characters sequentially

Tags: java

I'm working on a small project, it's about encrypting some words and sentences. But the idea was to replace characters multiple times in java.

When I replace a character like 'a' for example, with 'o' and then replace 'o' with 'b', all the 'a's and the 'o's become 'b'.

So is there any way to stop this?
And should I go on like so or use the `ReplaceAll` statement?
And what's the difference between each?

please help, and thank you for your help
code sample:

```java
String name = "Majd";
String res = name.replace('a','o').replace('o','b');
System.out.println(res);
```

output:

```
Mbjd
```

Comment: Why don't you use a loop?

Comment: Indeed. Not every programming problem has a built-in Java routine to do exactly what you want.

Comment: In your case, the `o` are also replaced by `b` which were previously an `a`, which you don't want if I understand correctly. Just change the replacement order. `String res = name.replace('o','b').replace('a','o');`

Answer (score 5):

You could do it by looping over the characters:

```
char[] cs = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; ++i) {
  switch (cs[i]) {
    case 'a': cs[i] = 'o'; break;
    case 'o': cs[i] = 'b'; break;
  }
}
String newStr = new String(cs);
```

Comment: `char[] cs = str.toCharArray();` you create here a new `char[]`. You should use `str.charAt()` instead.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik no. I use `toCharArray()` because I *want* to create a new `char[]`, because I can update that.

Comment: Why not use a switch expression instead of a statement? :)

Comment: Sure, you can do that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Matcher#replaceAll` with a callback.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a|o");
String name = "Majd";
Map<String, String> replacement = Map.of("a", "o", "o", "b");
String res = p.matcher(name).replaceAll(r -> replacement.get(r.group()));
System.out.println(res); // Mojd
```

Alternatively, to only replace single characters, you could iterate over them.

```
String res = name.chars()
         .mapToObj(i -> i == 'a' ? "o" : i == 'o' ? "b" : String.valueOf((char)i))
         .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: You can avoid creating all those single char strings with the streams approach: `intStream.collect(() -> new StringBuilder(name.length()), (sb, c) -> sb.append((char) c), StringBuilder::append).toString()`, or something like.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want an example without lambda.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] name = "aaaooo".toCharArray();
    String res = "";
        
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        switch (name[i]) {
        case 'a':
            res += "o";
            break;
        case 'o':
            res += "a";
            break;
        default:
            res += name[i];
        }
    }
        
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

Comment: If you're going to build a string one character at a time, use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static String encrypt(String str, Map<Character, Character> lowerCaseKeyMap) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char actual = str.charAt(i);
        char encrypted = lowerCaseKeyMap.getOrDefault(Character.toLowerCase(actual), actual);

        if (encrypted == '\0')
            encrypted = actual;
        else if (Character.isUpperCase(actual))
            encrypted = Character.toUpperCase(encrypted);

        buf.append(encrypted);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: I feel obliged to point out that you're also constructing a new `char[]` here, inside the `StringBuilder` :) `StringBuilder` is more useful in general; but if you're simply transposing the characters in a string (not changing length or positions of most characters), `char[]` is simpler and likely faster (no method calls etc).

Answer (score 0):

There’s no way to do it with built in methods.

If you’re swapping a lot of letters, store the transformations in a map:

```
Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>(){{
    put('a', 'o');
    put('o', 'b');
    // etc for all transformations
}};
```

Then steam the chars, mapping them to their new values and joining them into the result:

```
String encoded = str.chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
    .map(c -> map.getOrDefault(c, c)) // no change if no mapping found
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: It works fine @Bohemian, I confirm it ;) good job

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** And what's the difference between each?

**A:** Just the regex, both will replace all.

---

**Q:** And should I go on like so or use the ReplaceAll statement?

**A:** No

---

**S:** You can use opposite order:

```
String res = name.replace('o','b').replace('a','o');
```